# Summation problems within Plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the following double sum expression with mathematica.

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(k^2\tau^2+(x+2\pi r)^2+(y+2\pi s)^2)^{3/2}}$$

where $(k\tau)^2=\frac{1}{10}$.

But I keep getting an error, here is the code:

```
Plot3D[
Sum[((2πs+x)^2+(2πr+y)^2+(1/10)^2)^(-3/2)), {s,-Infinity,Infinity},
{r,-Infinity, Infinity}] //Evaluate,
{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}
]
```

and the error is:

```
NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) -((6. 3.14159 (-4.99929+2. 3.14159s))/
      (0.01 +(-4.99929+<<1>>)^2+(-4.99929+<<18>> s)^2)^(5/2)) is not numerical at point r = 0.
NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) -((6. 3.14159 (-4.99929+2. 3.14159 s))/
    (0.01 +(-4.99929+<<1>>)^2+(-4.99929+<<18>> s)^2)^(5/2)) is not numerical at point r = 0.
Plot3D::exclul: {Im[(2 \[Pi] s+x)^2+(2 \[Pi] r+y)^2]-0} must be a 
       list or equalities or real-valued functions.
Cloud::timelimit: This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan.
```

I would be grateful if someone can explain what is the problem.

Comment: Please edit your post and include your code, properly formatted in code blocks with proper *Mathematica* syntax, rather than screenshots.

Comment: Are you sure the sum converges?  Why not break the problems into steps? Try the double sums first, then evaluate that at some random (x,y) point and see.   Whenever you have larger problem, always break it down to smaller problems.

Comment: This doesn't sum to infinity, but might let you get started i=8; n=5; Plot3D[ Sum[1/(1/10+(x+2 Pi r)^2 + (y+2 Pi s)^2)^(3/2), {s,-i,i}, {r,-i,i}], {x,-n,n}, {y,-n,n}] and let you slowly increase the value of i

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @Nasser The double sum is not tractable with Mathematica, that's why I am trying to plot it to see how it behaves. Mathematica just returns the double sum when I try to do the evaluation.

Comment: Note that your sum is periodic in `x` and `y` with period 2*Pi.  Exploiting this periodicity (e.g. by fitting a function over one cycle) should make numerical exploration of this function more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* can't find symbolic `Sum` solution,only numerically.

By good advice @Bill.
You may increase `n` value.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] :=
With[{n = 10}, NSum[((2 Pi s + x)^2 + (2 Pi r + y)^2 + (1/10)^2)^(-3/2), 
{s, -n, n}, {r, -n, n}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]]

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

**Update**

Using `compile` I speedup calculation.It is **90** times faster.

```
n = 30;
func = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, 
Total@Table[
With[{r = Range[-n, n]}, 
Tr[((2 Pi s + x)^2 + (2 Pi r + y)^2 + (1/10)^2)^(-3/2)]], {s, 
Range[-n, n]}], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
Plot3D[func[x, y, n], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: It takes a lot of time. Maple produces that with n = 30  in a moment

Comment: What does Method -> "AlternatingSigns" means ?

Comment: This method speedup calculation twice than `Automatic`.I.m don't know why Mathematica takes a lot of time to calculation.

Comment: @user64494. I'm updated code,it fast as Maple.

Comment: The compiled version of your code  is faster than Maple one.